# How to click on a td created using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html-table

**html code**

```
 <input type="text" id="cal" />
 <div id="output"></div>
```

**function js**

```
function show_calendar () {
                $("#output").html("<div id='box' style='border: 1px solid black; width: 350px; height:auto; border-radius: 3px; padding: 3px;margin: 0px;'><div id='head' style='margin: 0px;padding: 3px;border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;height: 40px;border-radius: 3px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;text-align: center;line-height: 40px;background: #e9e9e9;'><div id='prec' style='margin: 0px;border: 1px solid black;height: inherit;width: 40px;float: left;'><div id='head-prec' style='cursor:pointer; position: relative;margin: 10px auto;width: 50%;height: 50%;border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 50%;background: #333333;'></div></div><span>" + title_month + " " +year+ "</span><div id='succ' style='margin: 0px;border: 1px solid black;height: inherit;width: 40px;float: right;'><div id='head-succ' style='cursor:pointer; position: relative;margin: 10px auto;width: 50%;height: 50%;border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 50%;background: #333333;'></div></div></div><div id='footer' style='margin: 0px;padding: 3px;height: auto;'><table style='margin: 0px auto;padding: 4px;'>");

                var thead = $('<thead><tr></tr></thead>')
                for (var i=0; i<=6; i++) {
                thead.append("<th style='padding: 2px;'>"+week_days[i]+"</th>");
                }
                $("#output table").append(thead);
                //other code here ...
                tr.append("<td id="+days_count+" style='text-align: right;border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;background: #f6f6f6;font-weight: normal;color: #454545;height: 22px; cursor:pointer'>"+days_count+"</td>");
                //other code here ...
```

**jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#cal").click(function() {
                $("#output").toggle("slow", function () {
                    show_calendar(); 
                });
            });

            $("td").click(function() {   //it doesn't work
                alert("clicked");
            });
        });
```

When I click on a td element in my table it doesn't work. Why? 
How can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'td', function(){
alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: @Fabio97 create jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m996dLxc/1/

Comment: @Fabio97 where is you table ??

Comment: `<table style='margin: 0px auto;padding: 4px;'>");` before of `var thead` at the end of line 21

Comment: @Fabio97 https://jsfiddle.net/m996dLxc/2/

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: put inside document ready, and included jquery...

Comment: What line where have you written this?

Comment: Because I copied all the code and I tried this in my page but it doesn't work

Comment: jquery included to page ?

Comment: Yes with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: heh, method on added in 1.7 version )

Comment: update jquery, or u want another solution ?

Comment: updated. thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$("td").click(function() {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click' , 'td', function() {
```